# Explanation of pandas DataFrame.assign() behaviour using lambda

Tags: pandas, dataframe, lambda

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(99)
rows = 10
df = pd.DataFrame ({'A' : np.random.choice(range(0, 2), rows, replace = True),
                    'B' : np.random.choice(range(0, 2), rows, replace = True)})


def get_C1(row): 
    return row.A + row.B

def get_C2(row): 
    return 'X' if row.A + row.B == 0 else 'Y'

def get_C3(row): 
    is_zero = row.A + row.B
    return "X" if is_zero else "Y"

df = df.assign(C = lambda row: get_C3(row))
```

Why the *get_C2* and *get_C3* functions return an error?

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking that `df.assign`, when passed a function, behaves like `df.apply` with `axis=1`, which calls the function for each row.

That's incorrect.

Per [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html#:%7E:text=Where%20the%20value%20is%20a%20callable%2C%20evaluated%20on%20df%3A) for [`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)

> Where the value is a callable, evaluated on *df*

That means that the function you pass to `assign` is called on the *whole dataframe* instead of *each individual row*.

---

*So,* in your function `get_C3`, the `row` parameter is not a row at all. It's a whole dataframe (and should be renamed to `df` or something else) and so `row.A` and `row.B` are two whole columns, rather than single cell values.

Thus, `is_zero` is a whole column as well, and `... if is_zero ...` will not work.